# Buy x number of Products from A and get x number of Products from B for free

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules

I'm a newbie in magento. I'm trying to add the Shopping Cart price rule "Buy X Get Y".

In my case, I want to let the user buy x number of Products from Product A and the user will receive the same amount of Products from Product B for free.

This can be done by adding a rule for each value of x, but that is meaningless.

Is there another way I can achieve this? Something like a loop?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

as far as i Know, you wont able to do using shopping cart rule only. Refer to below link he has some solution to this

http://blog.goods-pro.com/1733/magento-extension-buy-x-selection-of-products-get-another-y-selection-for-free/